# Makefile problems with java

Tags: java, makefile

I need to make a makefile to compile a couple of my java files to turn in but I have no idea how to do that. I searched the web with no luck. Currently my file is

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
        Proj411.java \
        ExecTime.java \
        Clocks.java \
        Instruction.java \


simulator: Proj411.java


Proj411.java: ExecTime.java Clocks.java Instruction.java

clean:
        $(RM) *.java
```

I want to make sure this is doing what I want it to do. Proj411 is where my main is located and it is dependent on the three other files to run.

Also on a side note, any explanation on what a makefile actually does may help. Thanks

Comment: I cheat. I have a `make.bat` that runs an `ant` script. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Java projects are usualy built with either Ant- or Maven- skripts, and are a bit more comfortable than the Makefile (-horror).
So try to move to ant, or maven. Ant may be a bit simpler.

Comment: My teacher specifically said makefile or I would have went a different route. Thanks though

Comment: If you want to learn for life, instead of "for school", then consider using ant, and go the standard route.

Comment: Unfortunately learning for life doesn't necessarily get you passing grades in school--no matter how incorrect the "for school" method is. A friend of mine has also been asked to deliver a Java project as a makefile for a school assignment--the reasoning being that the professor intends to use one script to grade C and Java versions of the same assignment. Strange but true.

Comment: Yes that can happen. And sometimes the teacher might to want an automatic check / build. And therfore all need the same build skript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the following line to your makefile:

```
classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)
```

Also, if you want to be able to just type "make" at the command line instead of "make simulator" you should add:

```
all: simulator
```